Find the minimum of $\sin (α-β-γ) \sin (α+β-γ) \sin (α-β+γ) \sin (α+β+γ)$
$α,β,γ\in\Bbb R,$
$$f(α,β,γ):=\sin (α-β-γ) \sin (α+β-γ) \sin (α-β+γ) \sin (α+β+γ)$$
Clearly, the maximum is $f(\frac{π}{2},\frac{π}{2},\frac{π}{2})=1$.
I guessed the minimum is $-1$, but$$f(α,β,γ)=f(-α,β,γ)=f(α,-β,γ)=f(α,β,-γ)$$so $f(\pm\frac{π}{2},\pm\frac{π}{2},\pm\frac{π}{2})=1$, it can't achieve $-1$.
Then I guessed the minimum is $f(\frac{π}{4},\frac{π}{4},\frac{π}{4})=-\frac14$.
Assuming $\cases{0\le-α+β+γ\le\pi\\0\leα+β-γ\le\pi\\0\leα-β+γ\le\pi\\0\leα+β+γ\le\pi}$,
Note that $(-α+β+γ)+(α+β-γ)+(α-β+γ)+(\pi-α-β-γ)=\pi$,
$$-f(α,β,γ)=\sin (-α+β+γ) \sin (α+β-γ) \sin (α-β+γ) \sin (\pi-α-β-γ)$$
$\sin(x)$ is concave on $[0,\pi]$, $\ln(x)$ is strictly increasing and concave on $(0,+\infty)$, so $\ln(\sin(x))$ is concave on $[0,\pi]$.
\begin{align}
\ln(-f(α,β,γ))&=\ln(\sin(-α+β+γ))+\ln(\sin(α+β-γ))\\&\phantom{=}+\ln(\sin(α-β+γ))+\ln(\sin(\pi-α-β-γ))\\&\leqslant 4\ln(\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))
\end{align}
by Jensen's inequality. So $-f(α,β,γ)\leqslant\frac14$.
What about other ranges of $α,β,γ$? The above assumed $-α$+$β$+$γ$,$α$+$β$$-γ$,$α$$-β$+$γ$,$α$+$β$+$γ$$\in$[$0$,$π$], we need to consider the other cases.

The region $\cases{0\le-α+β+γ\le\pi\\0\leα+β-γ\le\pi\\0\leα-β+γ\le\pi\\0\leα+β+γ\le\pi}$ is a tetrahedron.
SageMath plot (unit is $\pi$):
Polyhedron(vertices=[[-0.5,-0.5,1.0],[-0.5,1.0,-0.5],[1.0,-0.5,-0.5],[1.0,1.0,1.0]]).plot()


so the inequality is proved in this tetrahedron region. But we need to prove it in the whole space.
Translate the tetrahedron by $(\pi,0,0)$. Since $f(α,β,γ)=f(α+π,β,γ)$, the inequality is proved in the union of the two tetrahedrons.

Similarly, translate the tetrahedron by $(0,\pi,0)$ and $(0,0,\pi)$. Since $f(α,β,γ)=f(α,β+π,γ)=f(α,β,γ+π)$, the inequality is proved in the union of the 4 tetrahedrons.
t = Polyhedron(vertices=[[-0.5,-0.5,1.0],[-0.5,1.0,-0.5],[1.0,-0.5,-0.5],[1.0,1.0,1.0]])
show(t.plot(color='red') + Polyhedron(vertices=[[v[0] + 1, v[1], v[2]] for v in t.vertices()]).plot(color='red') + Polyhedron(vertices=[[v[0], v[1] + 1, v[2]] for v in t.vertices()]).plot(color='red') + Polyhedron(vertices=[[v[0], v[1], v[2] + 1] for v in t.vertices()]).plot(color='red'))


The question becomes, can the whole space be covered by translations of the tetrahedron by $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$, $n_1,n_2,n_3\in\Bbb Z$?

Should work the same. Note that $f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=f(\alpha+\pi,\beta, \gamma)=f(\alpha,\beta+\pi, \gamma)=f(\alpha,\beta, \gamma+\pi)$, so $f$ is periodic in all directions.

Also, just because $\ln(\sin(x))$ is concave it is not implied that $f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is concave. That would take more work (maybe you can use the second derivatives to test it)?

I suppose this function can be rewritten using prostaphaeresis formulas. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis

@hbghlyj Ah I see now that I read it wrong. Nice proof.

A brute-force search of whole-degree angles gives a minimum of $\frac{-1}{4}$, at $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 45°$ (and some other multiple-of-45° angles).  The maximum is indeed $1$.

Standard trigonometric formulae lead to the identity
$$\sin(\alpha-\beta-\gamma)\cdot\sin(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)\cdot\sin(\alpha-\beta+\gamma)\cdot\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\\[2ex]
 =\;\frac14 \big[\cos(2\gamma) -\cos(2\alpha)\cos(2\beta)\big]^2
-\frac14\sin^2(2\alpha)\sin^2(2\beta)$$
from which global max- and minimum values can be determined readily.
The Minimum: No constraints on $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb R,$ thus arrange for the sine squares to equal one, then pick $\gamma$ to make the squared bracket vanish. The suitable choice
$\,\frac\pi 4=\alpha=\beta=\gamma\,$ has already been mentioned by the OP.
The resulting value $-\frac14$ cannot be undercut since the product of the sines, without the prefactor $-\frac14$, is bounded above by $1$.

In order to obtain the RHS of the identity, the standard formulae
$$\left.\begin{matrix}\sin x\cdot\sin y \\ \cos x\cdot\cos y\end{matrix}\right\}
\;=\;\frac12[\,\cos(x-y)\,\mp\,\cos(x+y)\,]\tag{1}$$
are used, both forwards and backwards.
You may apply the sine variant
to the third and first factor (with $x=\alpha-\beta+\gamma, y=\alpha-\beta-\gamma$), and to the fourth and second factor (with $x=\alpha+\beta+\gamma, y=\alpha+\beta-\gamma$) to get
$$\frac14\big[\cos(2\gamma) -\cos(2(\alpha-\beta))\big]
\big[\cos(2\gamma) -\cos(2(\alpha+\beta))\big]$$
We consider this a quadratic polynomial in the variable $\cos(2\gamma)$, transform it into vertex form, and so eventually arrive at the RHS. On the way there we'll need
$$\cos(2(\alpha-\beta))+\cos(2(\alpha+\beta))\;=\;2\cos(2\alpha)\cos(2\beta)$$
by $(1)$ backwards, and
$$\cos(2(\alpha-\beta))\cdot\cos(2(\alpha+\beta))
\;=\;\frac12[\cos(4\alpha)+\cos(4\beta)] \;=\;\cos^2(2\alpha)+\cos^2(2\beta) -1$$
by the cosine variant in $(1)$, and furthermore using the double angle identity.
Completing the square asks to add and subtract $\,\cos^2(2\alpha)\cos^2(2\beta)$, thus the constant term, apart from the prefactor $\frac14$, equals
$$\begin{align}\cos^2(2\alpha)+\cos^2(2\beta) -1 -\cos^2(2\alpha)\cos^2(2\beta)
 &\;=\;\big(\cos^2(2\alpha)-1\big)\big(1-\cos^2(2\beta)\big)\\[1.5ex]
 & \;=\; -\sin^2(2\alpha)\sin^2(2\beta)\,.
\end{align}$$

Here is a bruteforce proof, using full expansion and Schur's inequality.
WolframAlpha can verify that
\begin{multline}
4\sin^2α\sin^2β\sin^2γ+\sin^4α+\sin^4β+\sin^4γ\\-2\sin^2β\sin^2γ-2\sin^2γ\sin^2α-2\sin^2α\sin^2β\\
=\sin (α-β-γ) \sin (α+β-γ) \sin (α-β+γ) \sin (α+β+γ)
\end{multline}
Let $a=\sinα,b=\sinβ,c=\sinγ,$ we will prove that
$$
4 a^2 b^2 c^2+a^4+b^4+c^4-2 b^2 c^2-2 c^2 a^2-2 a^2 b^2\ge-\frac{1}{4}
$$
Let $p=\sum a^2$, $q=\sum a^2b^2$, $r=a^2b^2c^2$, we need to prove that
$$4r+p^2-4q+\frac14\geqslant0,$$
When $p^2\geqslant4q$ then it is obviously true;
When $p^2<4q$, by Schur's inequality we have $r\geqslant(4pq-p^3)/9$, then we only need to prove that
$$\frac49(4pq-p^3)+p^2-4q+\frac14\geqslant0,$$
Since $p^2/4<q\leqslant p^2/3$, and the above expression is a linear function of $q$, we only need to verify that it holds when $q=p^2/4$ and $q=p^2/3$. Substituting the former gives $\hbox{LHS}=1/4>0$, and substituting the latter gives $\hbox{LHS}=(2p-3)^2(4p+3)/108\geqslant0$, thus the proof is complete.

Let $\alpha+\beta-\gamma=x$ etc,
$\implies x+y+z=?$
$$4\sin(- y)(\sin x)(\sin z)\sin(x+y+z)$$
$=(\cos(x+y)-\cos(x-y))(\cos(x+y)-\cos(x+y+2z))$ using Werner's formula
$=\cos^2(x+y)-2\cos(x+y)\cos(z+x)\cos(y+z)+\dfrac{2\cos^2(z+x)+2\cos^2(y+z)-2}2$ using Prosthaphaeresis formula
$=p^2-2qrp+q^2+r^2-1$ writing $\cos(x+y)=p$ etc.
$=(p-qr)^2-(1-q^2)(1-r^2)$
$$\ge-\sin^2(y+z)\sin^2(z+x)$$
$\ge-1$ (please notice the multiplier $4$ in the $3$rd line)
The equality occurs when $p=qr$ and $\sin(y+z)=\sin(z+x)=\pm1$
